# Play link youtube on webview

Tags: html

I want to play Youtube video on web-view using `iframe` but it is not working.
Youtube video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkWQDDv_qdg.

Comment: What's not working? Can you provide the code that is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is instead of using this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkWQDDv_qdg
```

I used this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/RkWQDDv_qdg
```

as the source of the `iframe` tag.

```
<iframe height="720" width="1280" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RkWQDDv_qdg">
</iframe>
```

Here is a fiddle that I created for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c47kmrnL/